# Simplifying the quotient $\frac{4x^4+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got stuck simplifying the following quotient. How to divide it?

$$\frac{4x^4+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+1}$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! Why don't you show your efforts ? Explain what you already tried and where you are stuck. By the way, long division ? Why does the title mention "logarithmic" ?

Comment: Where does the *logarithmic* equation enter here? Even worse: what this has to do with *division algebras* ?

Comment: nothing, I just want to divide the equation and remove the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^2+1$ does not divide $4x^4+2x^2+x+1$ without remainder, we can't remove the denominator. We can, though, divide through with remainder:

$\displaystyle \frac{4x^4+2x^2+x+1}{x^2+1}=4x^2+\frac{-2x^2+x+1}{x^2+1}=\boxed{4x^2-2+\dfrac{x+3}{x^2+1}}$

Comment: You won by 22 seconds ! Cheers

Comment: Cheers Claude, hahaha :)

Comment: +1 because my answer is basically the same as your answer, albeit presented a bit differently.